# Multiple comparison operators

Tags: c#

What is the standard way in C# to check if a number is within a range of numbers?

Typically, I would do some variation of this with int `i`:

```
return (i >= start && i <= end);
```

Is there no syntax for something like this:

```
// does not work
return (start <= i <= end);
```

Comment: Your first snippet is the standard way.

Comment: No, there is no syntax like the one you propose.

Comment: I think Ruby allows the second way but the first way is idiomatic in c, c++, Java and c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most close to what you expect is

```
return start <= i && i <= end;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no mathematical notations in C#. Operators are functions that return a result. Usually operators are either unary or binary only (i.e. you cannot pass 3 arguments).

One trick you can do is to introduce an extension method:

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static bool WithinRange(this int value, int low, int high)
        => value >= low && value <= high;
}
```

So the usage would be:

```
return i.WithinRange(start, end);
```

This is more verbose, but more obscure at the same time; does it mean to include lower bound? does it mean to include higher bound?

The suggestion is to stick to the syntax that any software developer knows.

Comment: Thank you for answer - although your syntax is off in your example.